# Linux base device not getting shutdown

Tags: linux, shutdown, reboot, init, poweroff

I try to shutdown my embedded system running with Linux environment using shutdown -h now. But in place of shutdown it is rebooting my system again. So can anyone give me suggestion how to shutdown my system or resolve this issue.

Or any possible reason of this issue?

Linux version is 2.37

Comment: Try the command: `init 0` ?

Comment: Still system is getting rebooted.

Comment: What's your embedded system?  Did it ever shutdown properly?  Does it even have the capability?  I have a Guruplug and it has no power management hardware, so when the system halts on `shutdown` it does just that, halt, and I have to power off manually.  This seems to be the case on many DD-WRT routers as well.

Comment: It's TI8148 based system and running with custom linux 2.37 provided from TI. Till today it is never shutdown. It always rebooted. Can you suggest me how to debug this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo shutdown 0
```

I have ubuntu and this is how I turn off the system.

Comment: Sorry but in my case it is not working, I tried almost all option coming with poweroff and shutdown command but board is never getting switched off it always get rebooted.

Comment: @ravibhuva9955 then try this: `shutdown -n` but the use of this option is discouraged, and its results are not always predictable.

Comment: Hi, I tried almost all option coming with poweroff and shutdown command but board is never getting switched off it always get rebooted. Can you suggest me how to debug this issue.

Comment: @ravibhuva9955 maybe if you disable the slash screen.
 Modifying `/etc/default/grub`. Comment out this line:
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
and add this one:
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""`
run `sudo update-grub` and then reboot to make the changes take effect. try again maybe you can see something.

Comment: It is my embedded system which is not having grub and we can't install anything at run time. Here what i find from some blogs is that if hardware is not designed such as it will get power off then it will not get power off. So what to do in this case can you suggest me something around this.

Comment: @ravibhuva9955 if it has linux it is has grub because it is who say where are the kernel and all important thing. Maybe the grub are embedded in the hardware. whats is it you system? Sorry for my english, this don't look very good.